# Keep ratio of a div when the font size changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a fixed width and height and a font size of 16px like the following

```
<div id="mydiv" style="font-size:16px;height:40px;line-height:40px;width:160px;background:orange;text-align:center;">
  hello world
</div>
```

I have an input text that allow changing the font size

```
<input type="text" id="input">

<button> change size </button>
```

JS :

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

  var value = $('#input').val();

  $('#mydiv').css('font-size', value + 'px');

});
```

If you enter a size of 30 for example the text will be out of the div, what I want to achieve is to keep the ratio, so when the font-size changes I want the div to change dimension keeping the aspect ratio. How I can do that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/mody5/x6t2dn3e/1/

Comment: Why are you not adjusting the `div` `width` and `height` accordingly?

Comment: And as a tip, stop using `px` and go for `em` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-calculate the `div` `width`, `height` and `line-height` when you change its `font-size`. By updating just its `font-size` alone, nothing else will be changed.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var div = $('#mydiv');

  // These methods return the value unit-less, so they'll be integers
  // if defined.
  var currentWidth = div.width();
  var currentHeight = div.height();

  // Parsing the values to make sure you got integers.
  var currentFontSize = parseInt(div.css('font-size'), 10);
  var currentLineHeight = parseInt(div.css('line-height'), 10);
  var value = parseInt($('#input').val(), 10);

  var newFontSize = value + 'px';

  // Here we keep the ratio between width and height, considering
  // the current and new font-size.
  var newWidth = ((currentWidth * value) / currentFontSize) + 'px';
  var newHeight = ((currentHeight * value) / currentFontSize) + 'px';
  var newLineHeight = ((currentLineHeight * value) / currentFontSize) + 'px';

  // Applying all the styles at once.
  div.css({
    fontSize: newFontSize,
    width: newWidth,
    height: newHeight,
    lineHeight: newLineHeight
  });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x6t2dn3e/7/)

Comment: It should be fine now.

Comment: I've found the error in this line  `var value = parseInt($('#input').val(), 10);` just should replace $(this) by $('#input') and it works like a charm :) thank you so much. By the way I am wondering how to do the opposite, I mean by changing width and height this time, change the text size automatically

Comment: It's all about maths. I'm sure you can figure it out. I've updated both the answer and the `jsFiddle` when I too saw the wrong element reference.

Comment: not really sure if I can figure it out as I am really bad at Maths haha :D Thank you anyway you've saved me a lot of headache in this answer :)

Comment: @EmmanuelB I answered the OP question taking into consideration what they chose to work with. If it was for my personal choice I would go for just `CSS`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Ok, I see :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use em values ? This is exactly what it's used for: apply values relatively to a font-size…

```css
.test {
  font-size:16px;
  height:2.5em;
  line-height:2.5em;
  width:10em;
  background:orange;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  hello world
</div>
```

Try change the font-size, you'll see all the div is growing. Use this website to help you calculate the good em values: http://pxtoem.com/

(And here's your update jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x6t2dn3e/9/ )

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of inline-block and padding in your style.

Something like this:

```
display:inline-block;padding:15px
```

See updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/donal/p3hrctsf/2/

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
 
  var value = $('#input').val();
  
  $('#mydiv').css('font-size', value + 'px');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" style="display: inline-block; font-size:16px;padding: 15px;background:orange;text-align:center;">
  hello world
</div>

<br>

<input type="text" id="input">
<button>Change Font Size</button>
```